# Code analysis of a jar/war/ear using sonar

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube5.1

I am new to **Sonarqube**. Can I perform code analysis of a jar/war/ear when I don't have source code available with me?

Answer (score 0):

Typically you should scan at the time of build. You will get results for both static code analysis (coding rules) as well as dynamics analysis (test results/code coverage).

However for static code analysis. You can always extract the artifact(war/jar/ear).

jar -xvf yourWARfileName.war

Then scan the extracted war. For Eg: in Jenkins you can point the scan to extracted jar in the workspace

Comment: Thanks. Can't we run static code analysis on extracted jar using Sonar?

Comment: Yes you can. You just need to tell Sonar what is your source location for the scan